# Spfx extension disappears from page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

I have created a spfx extension for my communication site, it is working perfectly when page is reloaded. When I click on search bar on the page then it takes me to the search page and when I return back to my page, my extension is not available on the page

Any idea how we can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick fix for the issue provided by the Rainson12 in the post below, you could refer to the quick fix.

[There is a similar post.](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1042)